# Does locking PC via screensaver or Winkey+L affects background processes

Tags: windows, screensaver, login-screen

As the question implies - will using the locking PC feature after idling for a while or using Winkey+L to lock the PC affects any background tasks, such as downloading or uncompressing files or server applications such as Samba/Plex?

Will Samba server/Plex or even Google Drive syncing still work even if the PC is at the login screen?

This is what I've found - but this one applies to Windows 7.  Will this one applies to Windows 8.1 Pro too?

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/e488e503-b116-4817-a845-51866e2e500c/start-l-does-locking-a-windows-7-home-premium-computer-suppend-applcation-execution-or-not?forum=w7itproui

Another question - will remote PC applications such as Teamviewer/Anydesk works when the PC cold boots into the login screen?

Answer (score 0):

> As the question implies - will using the locking PC feature after idling for a while or using Winkey+L to lock the PC affects any background tasks, such as downloading or uncompressing files or server applications such as Samba/Plex?

No. You should be a-okay as long as the device doesn't go into a hibernation or low-power state.

> Will Samba server/Plex or even Google Drive syncing still work even if the PC is at the login screen?

If by 'login screen' you mean the lock screen, then yes, that should still work.

If you meant an actual login screen, where you haven't logged in yet, then no, that won't work.

> Another question - will remote PC applications such as Teamviewer/Anydesk works when the PC cold boots into the login screen?

It depends. If you have teamviewer set up to do that (the settings: start when the computer boots up and also allow unmonitored remote access), then yes, that should work too. I cannot answer about Anydesk as I haven't used that before.

If those programs haven't been set up that way, then no, you'll have to log in to access that functionality.